# Objective C: objc_msgSend return type

Tags: objective-c

How to find out the type of the result of `objc_msgSend`?

From the docs:

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

that is, everything what `objc_msgSend` returns is of `id` type, right? But sometimes the function returns a proper Objective C object (when asking for a NSWindow +new) and sometimes it return just a bool (which is a C `char`).

How to differentiate between those various outcomes? How do I know whether it returned am object or a primitive type?

Edit: Thanks for the replies! One more question: isn't it at least possible to tell whether the returned type is primitive one or a proper object (and perhaps then query it by `object_getClass`)?

Comment: Note that this kind of dynamism is generally to be avoided;  Objective-C really is designed as a *statically compiled* language with *dynamic polymorphism at runtime*.  In particular, you are going to run into all kinds of hell if you try to support the generic C functional ABI (that would be required if you were to try and support all variants of return values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is runtime discovery of the return type, you can use the ObjC runtime API to lookup the method definition, then return type, of a given object method.  Specifically the methods:

`Method class_getInstanceMethod(Class aClass, SEL aSelector)`

or

`Method class_getClassMethod(Class aClass, SEL aSelector)`

will get you a `Method` struct, which you can subsequently query with

`void method_getReturnType(Method method, char *dst, size_t dst_len)`

to get the cstring description of the return type.  This description is not quite human readable - for instance, given your example, you would want to check if the string referenced in `*dst` is equal to "@".  If it is, then the return type is of type `id`. You can see a reference to the different type encodings [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100), and the ObjC runtime API methods I mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

As mentioned by H2C03, the `objc_msgSend_fpret` and `objc_msgSend_stret` variants should be used when the return type inferred from `method_getReturnType` indicates their use is appropriate (eg, when the return type would be a struct or float.  See the documentation notes on those two methods on the ObjC Runtime API docs page.)

Also, because I want you to have a good day, I feel like I should warn you about runtime code discovery typically being a bit brittle and usually a nasty performance smell. Anyways. :)

Comment: Although the type encodings are pretty much guaranteed not to change, it would be best (also for readability) to compare with `@encode(some-type)` rather than hard-coding.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow: `aClass` and `aSelector` presumes that the result of `objc_msgSend` is a valid object, no? What if it return a bool, how do I `class_getInstanceMethod` it? (And yes, it's runtime discovery)

Comment: Ecir: In this case you would get the type encoding before you ever called objc_msgSend. You query for information about the return type before you ever make the call, and alter your result datatype accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Callers of `objc_msgSend` are expected to already know the type being returned, and must effectively cast `objc_msgSend` to a function pointer type that returns the correct value. For instance, `-[NSString UTF8String]` would be invoked manually like this:

```
const char *cStr = ((const char *(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)
    (@"foo", @selector(UTF8String));
```

Yes, quite a mouthful, which is why it's usually a better idea to let the compiler do it. If you need more dynamism in sending messages, I recommend looking at [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first. Among other things, the method signature that an invocation is initialized with will include information about the return type and all arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can only know it from the method signature. Also, when returning floating-point numbers, `objc_msgSend_fpret`, and when returning structures, `objc_msgSend_stret` will be used.

If the returned value is an Objective-C object, you can query its class using `object_getClass()`.